# Manipulating individual tiles in an SVG pattern

Tags: javascript, svg, grid-system

So I've looked everywhere for the answer, but I couldn't find anything. I'm assuming it's because the way I'm trying to do it is not the right one, but I just want to make sure.

I'm trying to create an interactive grid for a web game (HTML, JS, CSS), in which every cell should change it's fill on hover/click. I need both a regular square grid, and a triangular grid. I want it to be vector based so that it will scale nicely to fit different screen sizes. I thought the easiest way would be to create a pattern and fill it on a rectangle. This is the code I have so far:

```
<pattern id="baseTile" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" )>
<path id="tile" d="M 0,0 L 0,10 10,10 10,0 Z" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
</pattern>
```

For the square, and this for the triangular grid:

```
<pattern id="baseTile" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<path d="M 5,0 L 10,2.5 10,7.5 5,10 0,7.5 0,2.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
<path d="M 5,0 L 5,10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
<path d="M 0,2.5 L 10,7.5" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
<path d="M 0,7.5 L 10,2.5" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
<path d="M 0,0 L 0,2.5 M 0,7.5 L 0,10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
<path d="M 10,0 L 10,2.5 M 10,7.5 L 10,10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".1" />
</pattern>
```

They produce the grids I need, but I don't know how to target each cell individually. I'm guessing since I've found no information on this, it's just not possible, and some other solution other than should be used. Any ideas?

Note: I posted this on Graphic Design, but just after posting, I realised here might be more appropriate, I apologise for the cross-post.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way, you'll need to have the grid consist of multiple elements (which could each be a single pattern that you swap if you want).

Comment: You can't interact with the contents of patterns.  Consider them fixed and static - like a bitmap texture.  So you have to do as Robert suggests and make a separate element for each tile.

Comment: My other question has been migrated, it is now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929382/manipulating-individual-tiles-in-an-svg-pattern/25945069?iemail=1&noredirect=1#25945069 Maybe this question can be closed, as the other one has been answered?